# Convert SqlDbType to .net Type

Tags: .net, ado.net

There are a lot of examples how do we convert SqlDbType enumeration from standard :net Classes or instances. I've not found any backward solution in internet. It seems to be much less common but the should be (I think) a simpler way then just a huge switch case over all 31 enumeration member.

Has anyone an idea how convert `SqlDbType` into .net Type in a better way then just switch over all possible enum values?

Thanks to  Tim Schmelter  comment. It seems thats is only solution.

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: Here is the mapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings 
Fill a dictionary with the SqlDbType as key and the clr-type as value. I don't know why .NET doesn't have such a dictionary.

Comment: In general, any code that's working at this boundary needs *specific* types on either side anyway (types in the result set/parameter, types in the variables/fields on the .NET side), so there's no real need for a generic mapping.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I maintain an open source package with hundreds of thousands of users which involves creating SQL tables on the fly. It uses `DataColumn` internally so there's definitely a need for a generic mapping. Of course, it isn't hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely odd that .NET doesn't include this mapping (and the SqlTypes are kind of a mess, too), but the "better way" is a dictionary keyed on the enum. This also makes it easy to test for validity if your project only supports a subset of the available column types. I maintain a project that deals with SQL table layouts defined on the fly. This way my library consumers only need to think in terms of `SqlDbType` without worrying about the internal `DataColumn` mappings.

```cs
internal static readonly Dictionary<SqlDbType, Type> equivalentSystemType = new Dictionary<SqlDbType, Type>
{
    { SqlDbType.BigInt, typeof(long) },
    { SqlDbType.Binary, typeof(byte[]) },
    { SqlDbType.Bit, typeof(bool) },
    { SqlDbType.Char, typeof(string) },
    { SqlDbType.Date, typeof(DateTime) },
    { SqlDbType.DateTime, typeof(DateTime) },
    { SqlDbType.DateTime2, typeof(DateTime) }, // SQL2008+
    { SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset, typeof(DateTimeOffset) }, // SQL2008+
    { SqlDbType.Decimal, typeof(decimal) },
    { SqlDbType.Float, typeof(double) },
    { SqlDbType.Image, typeof(byte[]) },
    { SqlDbType.Int, typeof(int) },
    { SqlDbType.Money, typeof(decimal) },
    { SqlDbType.NChar, typeof(string) },
    { SqlDbType.NVarChar, typeof(string) },
    { SqlDbType.Real, typeof(float) },
    { SqlDbType.SmallDateTime, typeof(DateTime) },
    { SqlDbType.SmallInt, typeof(short) },
    { SqlDbType.SmallMoney, typeof(decimal) },
    { SqlDbType.Time, typeof(TimeSpan) }, // SQL2008+
    { SqlDbType.TinyInt, typeof(byte) },
    { SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, typeof(Guid) },
    { SqlDbType.VarBinary, typeof(byte[]) },
    { SqlDbType.VarChar, typeof(string) },
    { SqlDbType.Xml, typeof(SqlXml) }
    // omitted special types: timestamp
    // omitted deprecated types: ntext, text
    // not supported by enum: numeric, FILESTREAM, rowversion, sql_variant
};
```

Comment: FWIW, `timestamp` and `rowversion` are the same thing and map to `Byte[]`. I think `sql_variant` can be mapped to`Object`.